# PHP Not Inserting Variable Into mySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having trouble getting one of my variable to be successfully inserted into my mySQL query.  Here is the query string:

```
$strShipMethodInfo = "SELECT BAMMDD, BAYY, BAXXX, ORDNUM, SHPNUM, \"SHIPMENT METHOD\", \"SHIPMENT STATUS\" FROM SHPPMTHD WHERE BAMMDD = " . $BAMMDD . " AND BAYY = " . $BAYY . " AND BAXXX = " . $BAXXX . " AND SHPNUM = " . $arrShippingInfo[$x]['SHPNUM'] . " AND ORDNUM = '" . $ORDNUM . "' ORDER BY SHPNUM";
```

I am using `$arrShippingInfo[$x]['SHPNUM']` in another query that is very similar, and it is putting the variable in that one.  However, when I do it with this query, it comes back as blank.  All the other values (`BAMMDD`, `BAYY`, `BAXXX`, etc.) are successfully put in, but the variable for `SHPNUM` does not get put in.

I have tried everything I can think of, thinking that it might be a quote in the wrong place, but I have been unsuccessful.  Could anyone please help me figure this out?  Thanks.

EDIT: I did a `print_r` on the string, and it printed twice... once with the `SHPNUM` correctly inserted and once with it blank.  Turns out it was a logic error in the for loop I was using (I needed to run the query for each shipment in the order).  `<` somehow got changed to `<=` so once I changed that it worked.  Thank you everyone for your responses.

Comment: If you dump your variable before trying to put it in the query, what do you get ?

Comment: But this is not your INSERT query, how could we help you?

Comment: Is SHPNUM a numeric or string type? If string, you are missing some single quotes before and after the value.

Comment: @codingbiz The OP is trying to insert PHP values into the query, not into the database.

Comment: We really can't help you without much more code.

Comment: Try$strShipMethodInfo = "SELECT BAMMDD, BAYY, BAXXX, ORDNUM, SHPNUM, 'SHIPMENT METHOD', 'SHIPMENT STATUS' FROM SHPPMTHD WHERE BAMMDD = '" . $BAMMDD . "' AND BAYY = '" . $BAYY . "' AND BAXXX = '" . $BAXXX . "' AND SHPNUM = '" . $arrShippingInfo[$x]['SHPNUM'] . "' AND ORDNUM = '" . $ORDNUM . "' ORDER BY SHPNUM";

Comment: If this database design isn't tied down yet, please remove spaces from all your table and field names you will make your life much much easier.

Comment: This has been answered correctly below. He's just forgetting the single quotes around where he is concatenating the variables. The result is a query without proper quotes.

Comment: and don't forget your code is open to SQL Injection attack. Parameterized query (PDO, mysqli, etc) would help you with a better security than concatenating variables like this.

Comment: You also need to check if the array has values or the index is even correct. What I could see is 'SHPNUM' is accessed with array while the others that worked are not array-related. My guess is with the array `$arrShippingInfo`

Comment: I found the issue with my query string.  See above.  Thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there is something wrong with how you are accessing that array value, either with the $x variable, or in how you are passing in the raw array value to the string (hard to say without the rest of your code: try assigning it to $SHPNUM and putting $SHPNUM into the statement?).

Within your code try running an:

```
echo $x; echo $arrShippingInfo[$x]['SHPNUM'];
var_dump($arrShippingInfo);
```

and you should be able to find the issue.

Using dummy data with your statement and running that code through on my end as:

```
<?php

$BAMMDD = 'bamddd';
$BAYY = 'BAYY';
$BAXXX = 'BAXXX';
$arrShippingInfo[0]['SHPNUM'] = '54';
$ORDNUM = 555;

$x = 0;
$strShipMethodInfo = "SELECT BAMMDD, BAYY, BAXXX, ORDNUM, SHPNUM, \"SHIPMENT METHOD\", \"SHIPMENT STATUS\" FROM SHPPMTHD WHERE BAMMDD = " . $BAMMDD . " AND BAYY = " . $BAYY . " AND BAXXX = " . $BAXXX . " AND SHPNUM = " . $arrShippingInfo[$x]['SHPNUM'] . " AND ORDNUM = '" . $ORDNUM . "' ORDER BY SHPNUM";

echo "<pre>$strShipMethodInfo</pre>";
?>
```

Produces:

> SELECT BAMMDD, BAYY, BAXXX, ORDNUM, SHPNUM, "SHIPMENT METHOD",
>   "SHIPMENT STATUS" FROM SHPPMTHD WHERE BAMMDD = bamddd AND BAYY = BAYY
>   AND BAXXX = BAXXX AND SHPNUM = 54 AND ORDNUM = '555' ORDER BY SHPNUM

Answer (score 1):

```
$strShipMethodInfo = "SELECT BAMMDD, BAYY, BAXXX, ORDNUM, SHPNUM, \"SHIPMENT METHOD\", \"SHIPMENT STATUS\" FROM SHPPMTHD WHERE BAMMDD = '" . $BAMMDD . "' AND BAYY = '" . $BAYY . "' AND BAXXX = '" . $BAXXX . "' AND SHPNUM = '" . $arrShippingInfo[$x]['SHPNUM'] . "' AND ORDNUM = '" . $ORDNUM . "' ORDER BY SHPNUM";
```

Added quotes(`'`) in the `where` condtion

Comment: OP as he described is trying to put the value into the statement he is building, not an issue of quotes.